# Click on a cell and have it's text/value assigned to another cell

Tags: excel, vba, cell

title pretty much sums it up,

simply,I want to be able to click on cell A2 and have it's contents automatically assigned to cell A15

ultimately the "user" would pick a cell A2, or B2, or C2 etc and have the selected cell's value assigned to A15

interface

[image: 1]

searched all over U tube but just about anything related is 5+ years old

thank you for your time and consideration

Comment: "just about anything related is 5+ years old" - nothing much has changed in the last 20 years, so that's not a problem.  Look at the Worksheet_SelectionChange event.

Comment: What have you tried with this solution? WorksheetChangeEvent assigning the selected value to A15 should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

- Right click on sheet tab > `View Code`, paste the code

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const SRC_RANGE = "A2:C2" ' modify as needed
    Const DES_CELL = "A15"
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range(SRC_RANGE)) Is Nothing Then
                Me.Range(DES_CELL).Value = .Value
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```